# Can I assign a function in an excel add-in to a button in the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a button in the sheet that you can press that will run part of the add in. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess this is in continuation to your previous question. Why not create the button in the Excel menu so that it is available to all workbooks? See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140930%28v=office.10%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163587%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: can i do that in such a way that someone on a different machine can use it without changing the ribbon etc?

Comment: If the user installs the adding then it will automatically create a new tab in the ribbon :)

Comment: ok ill look into that. but is there a way to do so with a button in a sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ok ill look into that. but is there a way to do so with a button in a sheet? – Jacxel 7 mins ago

Yes you can.

I am assuming that you have an Add-In called `MyAddIn.xlam` and you have a procedure called `Sample()' in the module of the Add-In. I am also assuming that the Add-In is installed.

Replace the file `MyAddIn.xlam` with the relevant Add-In name and replace the procedure `Sample` with the relevant procedure name.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Run "MyAddIn.xlam!Sample()"
End Sub
```